# Batik does not support style with vector-effect=non-scaling-stroke

Tags: svg, batik

When you open the non-scaling-stroke.svg[check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxH-HxZnRRaNa2l1UXpWdWlTRjg/view?usp=sharing] on chrome or FF you will see that the middle line is scaled as per vector-effect = 'non-scaling-stroke'

When you transcode to JPEG using batik the... vector-effect = 'non-scaling-stroke' is not getting supported. The output i get is  non-scaling-stroke1.jpeg[check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxH-HxZnRRaNQjNRQk50WTRDX28/view?usp=sharing]

How can I fix this am I missing on something.

Comment: Download the source code to Batik and implement the feature or scale the shape yourself in javascript so it's always the right width.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but there are so many dependencies, where can I find the code to manage the stroke width..:(